# Node js lamba not waiting for db event to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which connect to MySQL and stream data to aws sqs, this code runs fine in local but when ran in lambda the function terminate before publishing event to sqs , lambda in not waiting for event loop to finish.

following is the code.

```
exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true;
    console.log("running handler");
    query().then((message)=>{
      console.log("sucess++++ " + message);
      resolve(message);
    },(error)=>{
      console.log("Error++ " + error);
      reject(error);
    });
  })

};

function query() {
  logger.info("inside query()");
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    try {
      connection =  mysql.createConnection({
        host: HOST,
        user: USER,
        password: PASSWORD,
        port: PORT
      });
      const dateObject =  getDateObject();
      console.log('dateobject ' + dateObject);
      let sql =  fs.readFileSync('./sql/test.sql').toString();
      const finalSql =  sql.replace(/{dateString}/g, dateObject);
      // logger.info("running query " + finalSql);
       console.log(finalSql);
      var query =  connection.query(finalSql);
     query
        .on('error', async function (err) {
          logger.error("error while running query " + err);
          reject(err);

        })
        .on('fields', function (fields) {
        })
        .on('result', async function (row) {
          // connection.pause();
          await processRow(row);
        })
        .on('end', async function () {
          logger.info("all rows have been received");
          //logger.info("closing connections");
          resolve("sucesss");
          connection.end();
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      logger.error(error);
    }
  })


}

// };

 async function processRow(row) {
  await sendMessage(row);
}

 function getDateObject() {

  //return dateObj;
}

async sendMessage(message) {
    let messageBody = {};
    messageBody['Subject']="xyz";
    messageBody['Message']= JSON.stringify(message);
    var params = {
      DelaySeconds: 0,
      QueueUrl: SQS_URL,
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify(messageBody)
    }
    this.sqs.sendMessage(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        logger.error("Error" + err);
      } else {
        logger.info("Success" + data.MessageId);
      }
    });
  }
```

Earlier I tried with async await instead of promise but stills it doesn't work as expected

the result I get is

```
sucess++++ sucesss
```

and it terminate after that without publishing the message.
If I use timeout() in the handler and make the function wait then it works fine.

any reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that `mysql.createConnection`, `getDateObject`, `connection.query(finalSql)` are executing synchronously?

Comment: @Dijkstra yes I tried them with async await also but still it gives the same result.

Comment: If it's returning before the async code has completed, then you're not using async/promises correctly.

Comment: @404 yes there was a problem with one function , now it is resolved , thanks :)